# FMOD Get Parameter OK, Set Parameter ERR_INVALID_PARAM

Tags: fmod

I have code that gets a parameter and then sets a parameter.  The get works fine, but the set returns ERR_INVALID_PARAM:

```
            FMOD.RESULT getResult = FMODManager.GetCurrentMusicInstance().getParameterByName(PianoVolumeParamter, out pianoParameter);
        Debug.Log("Get Result " + getResult);

        FMOD.RESULT result = FMODManager
            .GetCurrentMusicInstance()
            .setParameterByName(PianoVolumeParamter, 1f);
        Debug.Log("Set Result " + result);
```

What am I doing wrong?  This is FMOD for Unity 2.01.07.  The max value for PianoVolume is 1f, the min is 0f.  It's a continuous parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'd accidentally set the parameter type to Global and you can't change Global parameters this way.  Totally my mistake.